# Help me to simplify $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{r}{2}\rfloor}\binom{r}{i}\binom{r-i}{r-2i}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I tried to simplify $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{r}{2}\rfloor}\binom{r}{i}\binom{r-i}{r-2i}$ by using generating function in the similar way of markus-scheuer's answer to the question [How to prove $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{r}{2}\rfloor}\binom{r}{i}\binom{r-i}{r-2i}2^{r-2i}=\binom{2r}{r}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277706/how-to-prove-sum-limits-i-0-lfloor-fracr2-rfloor-binomri-binomr). What I got is $[u^r](1+u+u^2)^r$. I don't know how to compute the coefficient of $u^r$ in $(1+u+u^2)^r$. I tried using by trinomial expasion but I didn't suceed.

Comment: You could try using a binomial expansion?  $$(1+u+u^2)^r=\sum_{n=0}^r{\binom{r}{n}u^n(1+u)^n}$$

Comment: You might try $1+u+u^2 = (1-u^3)(1-u)^{-1}$

Comment: If you carefully compute the sum for the first few values of $r$ and then search the OEIS, you should find https://oeis.org/A002426 -- there are lots of formulas there, but none of them seem to be the simple kind of expression you're looking for, which suggests there might not be one. Unless I overlooked something; there's a lot in the entry!

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven On RHS $(1+u)^nu^{2r-2n}$. After simplifying also I got expression like in the question.

Comment: @BarryCipra I taught the link you suggested is very helpful because I want to represent the numbers 1,3,7,19,51,141,393,...Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There   is  no closed form available for the  *[central trinomial coefficients](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralTrinomialCoefficient.html)*
\begin{align*}
[u^r](1+u+u^2)^r&=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor r/2\rfloor}\binom{r}{i}\binom{r-i}{r-2i}
=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor r/2\rfloor}\binom{r}{2i}\binom{2i}{i}
\end{align*}

> **Plausibility check:**
>
> We consider the more general expression 
>   $$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor r/2\rfloor}\binom{r}{i}\binom{r-i}{r-2i}t^{r-2i}$$
>    and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor r/2\rfloor}}&\color{blue}{\binom{r}{i}\binom{r-i}{r-2i}t^{r-2i}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^\infty[z^{i}](1+z)^{r}[u^{r-2i}](1+tu)^{r-i}\tag{1}\\
> &=[u^r](1+tu)^r\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\frac{u^2}{1+tu}\right)^i[z^i](1+z)^r\tag{2}\\
> &=[u^r](1+tu)^r\left(1+\frac{u^2}{1+tu}\right)^r\tag{3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=[u^r](1+tu+u^2)^{r}}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We observe in case of $t=2$ the nice simplification
>   \begin{align*}
> [u^r](1+2u+u^2)^{r}=[u^r](1+u)^{2r}=\binom{2r}{u}
> \end{align*}
>   Regrettably there is no obvious similar simplification for other values of $t$.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* operator twice and set the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ without changing anything, since we are adding zeros only.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator, do some rearrangements and use the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [u^{p-q}]A(u)=[u^p]u^qA(u)
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $z:=\frac{u^2}{1+tu}$
  \begin{align*}
  A(u)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i u^i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty u^i [z^i]A(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we do some simplifications.

> **Notes from the experts:**
>
> D.E. Knuth gives in *[Concrete Mathematics](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*, Appendix A 7.56 the following representation of a more general expression
>
> \begin{align*}
> [u^r](a+bu+cu^2)^r=[u^r]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2bu+(b^2-4ac)u^2}}
> \end{align*}
>
> He states that according to the paper *[Hypergeometric Solutions of Linear Recurrences with Polynomial Coeffcients](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.374.8662&rep=rep1&type=pdf)* by Marko Petkovšek there exists a closed form (more precisely: a closed form solution as a finite sum of hypergeometric terms) if and only if
>   $$\color{blue}{abc(b^2-4ac)=0}$$
>
> In case of central trinomial coefficients we have $a=b=c=1$. Since then the expression $abc(b^2-4ac)=-3\ne 0$
>   there is no such closed form in particular for the central trinomial coefficients.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I learned solving by generating function method by you only. Your efforts are amazing for helping research scholars. Thanks again...

Comment: @Dhanalakshmi: You're welcome! Many thanks for your nice comment! ... and good to see the answer(s) are useful. :-)

Comment: +1. Very nice your 'Notes from the experts'. I have the book but never read that Appendix. I'll check it.

Comment: Really nice answer. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

The central trinomial coefficient ([A002426](https://oeis.org/A002426)): the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x+x^2)^n$, is given by:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \binom{n}{i;2n-2i-2\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor;i}$$

because $i$ represents the number of $2$'s, $2n-2i-2\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor(=n-2i+n-2\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor)$ represents the number of $1$'s and $i$ represents the number of $0$'s in a partition of $n$ into $\{0,1,2\}$.

For example, $n=6$, we have $222000,221100,211110,111111$, represented in multinomial format as $303,222,141,6$.

So the sum is:

$$\frac{720}{3!0!3!}+\frac{720}{2!2!2!}+\frac{720}{1!4!1!}+\frac{720}{6!}$$
$$=20+90+30+1$$
$$=141$$

Comment: Thank you I tried using trinomial expantion but I didn't get. But I need in more simple form. I don't know whether it is possible or not. I taught I want to look the link you suggested. thanks a lot