# Finding $ \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k A_k {n \choose k}, ~\text{if}~ (1+x+x^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} A_k x^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, binomial-theorem

Finding $S=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k A_k{n\choose k}$,
if
$(1+x+x^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} A_k x^k.$
\begin{align}
(1+x+x^2)^n &= A_0+A_1x+A_2x^2+\dots+A_nx^n+\dots+A_{2n}x^{2n} \\
(1-1/x)^n &= {n \choose 0}-{n \choose 1}x^{-1}+{n\choose 2}x^{-2}+\dots+(-1)^nx^{-n}
\end{align}

Multiplying these two we get $S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k A_k {n \choose k}=\text{Coefficient of $x^0$ in } (x^3-1)^n/x^n$

Or $S=\text{Coefficient of $x^n$ in } (x^3-1)^n=0$, when $n$ is not a multiple of $3$.

The question is how else we can prove this result? How to modify this result when $n$ is a multiple of $3$ (that is, $n=3p$)?

**EDIT** I find that if $n=3p$, then $S= \text{Coefficient of}~ x^{3p}$ in $(x^3-1)^{3p}={3p \choose p}$

Comment: 1/ Can you clarify with specific details how you are "multiplying these two"? It seems to be some very wishful thinking on your part about how to obtain an involution?  Also, what makes you say that coefficeint of $x^n$ in $(x^3 - 1)^n$ is 0, especially when $n$ is a multiple of 3? EG it doesn't hold for $n = 3$.

Comment: @Calvin Lin I am multiplying the two series so that the product $P(x)= (1+x+x^2)^n(x-1)^n/x^n=(x^3-1)^n/x^n=S x^0+\text{other powers of}~ x$

Comment: @Calvin Lin thanks my result is limited to the cases when $n$ is not a multiple of 3., I have corrected it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a different approach, but a convenient notation which might be useful. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kA_k\binom{n}{k}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k[x^k]\left(1+x+x^2\right)^n\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k[x^k]\left(\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}\right)^n\\
> &=[x^0]\left(\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)^k\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^0]\left(\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}\right)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^n\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^n]\left(x^3-1\right)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=[x^n]\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{n}{q}x^{3q}(-1)^{n-q}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=
> \begin{cases}
> \binom{n}{n/3}&\quad 3\ |\ n\\
> 0&\quad 3\not|\ n
> \end{cases}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (2) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (3) we simplify the expression and apply the same rule as in (1) again. We expand the binomial in the following line.
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^n$.

Comment: Very nice solution. Can we find $A_k$ explicitly?

Comment: @ZAhmed It might help to recognize that $A_k$ is the number of compositions of $k$ into $n$ parts of size $0$, $1$, or $2$.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A027907

Comment: @ZAhmed: Many thanks! :-) In order to determine $A_k$ you might find *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291711/help-me-to-simplify-sum-limits-i-0-lfloor-fracr2-rfloor-binomri-b/2296243#2296243)* helpful.